# Set HTTP response headers vs Server Configuration

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, http-headers, penetration-testing

I'm aware of that using http response headers we can force additional security measures on java web applications.
As an example I have used

```
 resp.setHeader( "X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN" );
 resp.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains;")
```

But still the penetration test which was done by a third party(Symantec) shows the same issues. I was wondering whether I have to configure something in Application Server(Tomcat 6 and JBOSS 5 and 6) as well.

Reference : https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security/

Comment: you said "same issues". Please clarify what are they.

Comment: Earlier another third party has raised the above mentioned issues as security threats. Later I have fixed them using above mentioned headers. Even I have tried to perform the clickjack by myself. 
Recently Symantec has performed a pen test and reported same fixed issues as informative items.

Comment: Weird... I had a similar experience.  I have these headers set via Tomcat configuration and a pen test flagged these headers as missing.  I don't understand!